# netplan: Why does it generate the back-end configuration at boot time and what is the consequence?

Tags: boot, netplan

I'm trying to understand how netplan is working exactly and I get stuck at the following technical design concept:

From [netplan introduction](https://netplan.io/reference/#introduction):

> During early boot, the netplan “network renderer” runs which reads
> /{lib,etc,run}/netplan/*.yaml and writes configuration to /run to hand
> off control of devices to the specified networking daemon.

This is because of the [netplan key goal](https://netplan.io/design/#key-goals):

> No persistent generated config, only original YAML config

I do not understand, why netplan does follow this design concept. What is the reason and/or advantage of a non persistent back-end configuration, that is generated every time, the system does boot?

And in addition to that: What do I need to take care about, if I would work on a network configuration by editing the back-end configuration using one of the well known methods?

A reason for a mix of using netplan along with a back-end configuration tool could be e.g., that most of the network configruation is covered by using netplan, but for a specific part there would be the need to edit the configuration without netplan, because netplan does not support the needed capability (yet).

Would be the only way to resolve such a situation by leaving netplan alone and start just using pure networkd, even though one of a couple of connections/interfaces would be affected only?

**This question is about understanding netplan only! I do not have any technical issues with netplan currently!**

Thank you!

Comment: "why" is because Netplan reads its config file when it is started...and it is started at every boot.

Comment: What do you mean the *"configuration is generated at boot time"*? Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I do appologize for not asking precisely enough! Sorry, if I did waste some people time! I did edit my question, to make it more understandable.